# Unable to stop Activity from opening again in Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin, android-activity, xamarin.android

I have used `FinishAndRemoveTask();` inside `stop()` method to so that it can remove the Activity form opening again, but this works when i press `Overview` button and try to open the activity, but when i press `Back button` and press the Activity again from overview the `Activity` opens again.  Is there a way to completely remove Activity from Recent apps list when pressing `Back` button or `overview` button ?

```
protected override void OnStop()
    {
        base.OnStop();

        FinishAndRemoveTask();
    }
```

Comment: Umm, what exactly do you want? On click of overview button you do not want it to show your app or what?

Comment: yes, i don't want to see it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this problem by overriding `OnBackPressed()` method in the Activity:

```
public override void OnBackPressed() {
            FinishAndRemoveTask();
}
```

Comment: i will check it

Answer (score 1):

In your Activity caller intent add the following and it should work:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(YourActivity));
intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ExcludeFromRecents);
```

Comment: i tried it but it works only with overview, it clears when i click my app from overview, but when i press back button it is clickable to open again, i don't want it to be there at all.

Comment: What do you mean that when you press the back button? Are you using this code in the caller intent of the activity it goes back to?